# How to return a response value from .post() into my function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, scope

I have some javascript validation where I check (among other things) if an email is taken, but I can't get it to work.

```
function validateField(input) {

    errors = false;
    messages = ''; //

    /*  Begin checks */

    if (input.hasClass('jEmailUnique')) {

        message = 'Email not taken';

        $.post('../ajax/j_validate.php', {

            step: 1,
            email: input.val()
        }, function(response){

            if (response != '0') {

                message = tipInvalid + message;

                errors = true;
            }
            else {

                message = tipValid + message;
            }

            messages += "<p>" + message + "</p>";
        });
    }

    /* End checks */

    if (errors == true) {

        input.addClass('jHasError').removeClass('jNoError');
    }
    else {

        input.addClass('jNoError').removeClass('jHasError');
    }

    setTip(input, messages); // show pop up window with error messages
}
```

Am I losing the scope of `messages` in the anonymous function in the `post` or something?

Comment: It is an asynchronous request. So the request will still be in progress while you are trying to use the `messages`  var. Which isn't yet filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My guess is I'm losing the scope of messages in the anonymous function in the post. How can I pass these through?

You're not, but you're still doing it wrong. Your `messages` variable is global. Tack a `var` in front of it to scope it to its function.

You also need to call `setTip(input, messages)` in the callback, before then, `messages` is `undefined`.